# Does an epimorphism factor any morphism with the same codomain?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, epimorphisms

Suppose that $f: A \to B$ is an epimorphism and $x: X \to B$ is a morphism. Is it true that there exists a morphism $y: X \to A$ such that $f \circ y = x$? Is it necessary that the category is abelian?

I can't see how I might prove this, but also I can't think of an example of an abelian category where it is not true.

Comment: Yes that is very helpful. My question then becomes, is there a type of category in which every object is projective? Obviously Set is one such category, but is there a more general class of such categories?

Comment: Certainly, if $f$ is a *split* epimorphism then such a $y$ exists.  And conversely, if such a morphism $y$ exists in the case that $x$ is the identity on $B$, then that says exactly that $f$ is a split epimorphism.